# Best practices for wrapping web app for Android

Tags: android, web-applications

Im looking into wrapping a existing web app for Android. Im doing some research to find the bets ways to do this?

Does anyone have any good links or tips that might be good to know?

Thankful for advice!

Comment: Please don't do this. I hate wrapped web-views. Users will use their web browser if they wish to use a web site. Please just make a native app.

Comment: @JoeSimpson What do you hate exactly?  I bet you use wrapped apps all the time and don't even realize it.

Comment: I don't actually. I can tell Instagram uses a WebView for the news feed and it's awful because it is really slooowww

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to wrap the web app in a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). The android dev guide also has a whole [section on things you should do when wrapping](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Comment: Is this answer still true ten years later? Or did the technology change in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the meaning of your wrapping. 
But if you want a tool to make an application that looks like a native android app but instead use the the web technology, you can use PhoneGap.

Find it [here](http://phonegap.com)

Comment: I don't think this is what they were asking for at all. He said specifically "existing web app".

Comment: uh.. sure it is better to use webview directly for "existing web app" because phonegap use this too. Just as i said, it depends on what is the meaning of his "wrapping"

Comment: My understanding was you can't use exsiting webapps in phonegap because you have to make phonegap specific api calls in order to access device functionality. If he doesn't wan't to change very much about his code (my interpretation of what he meant by wrapping), then I don't think phonegap is correct.